# How to write sign "|" (or) in LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex

I've tried to write `\textit{P(E\ell H)}` or `\textit{P(E\| H)}` to write `|` sign . But it didn't work.

Comment: Normally logical or is denoted by a wedge pointing downwards: `∨` (U+2228 LOGICAL OR).  In LaTeX this symbol is available as `\lor`.

Comment: In case you are trying to typeset source code snippets or other verbatim text in your document, better use packages like `listings` or `minted` that provide commands for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Might \mid be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to typeset "the conditional probability of event E given event H", you should write it -- in math mode -- as

```
P(E \mid H)
```

or, better yet,

```
\Pr(E \mid H)
```

The macro `\Pr` is a "math operator" and its output (the letter pair "Pr") is typeset using upright Latin letters. The macro `\mid` inserts a vertical bar and surrounds it with whitespace, as is appropriate for a relational operator symbol.

In TeX and LaTeX, there is an absolutely fundamental distinction between text mode and math mode. Do familiarize yourself with the basics of LaTeX coding. A good starting point is the document [A (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort), which is available in about two dozen languages.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$P(E \mid H)$ or, better yet, $\Pr(E \mid H)$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use either `|` or `\mid`. Using `\mid` is better as this adds the appropriate amount of spacing around the operator.

More importantly, you should enclose all of these in `$...$` to put them in math-mode. You will get an error if you use `\ell` or `mid` outside of math-mode.

Compare:

[image]

The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{}
\begin{document}

text: P(E$\ell$ H) or P(E|H) or P(E$\mid$ H)

math-mode: $P(E\ell H)$ or $P(E|H)$ or $P(E\mid H)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you mean `P(E${}\mid{}$H)`?

Comment: @HenriMenke No, I didn't. I was contrasting using math-mode against not using math-mode and I am strongly in favour of using it. Rather this this I would in any case use `P(${\mid}$H)` :)

Comment: The braces around everything in math mode are superfluous. `P($\mid$)H` does exactly the same.

Comment: @alephzero : Are you sure? Look at $3+$ and $3+{}$ and you will see that they are different. And there is good reason for that. (But I'm not sure if that's what you meant.)

Comment: @alephzero That's not true. Braces around an operator in math-mode remove the spacing around it. Try comparing `$A\mid B$` and  `$A{\mid}B$`.

Comment: it worked too. Thank you guys.